# MAC verified OK not showing when running Openssl

Tags: openssl

The tutorials I read  when running SSL commands state I would see MAC verified OK after running the any creation commands. I don't see that output but the files are created fine. Is that an issue?  I'm using PowerShell for Openssl v 3.0.7.

Example:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in website.xyz.com.pfx -clcerts -nokeys -out cert-file.pem
```

That should give a print of:

```
input password: 
MAC verified OK
```

But it doesn't appear.

Comment: Were you able to figure out the reason?I am having a similar issue and am not able to figure out the root cause

Comment: **Your tutorial is out of date.** That output occured in older versions of OpenSSL, but was dropped by 1.1.0 in 2016.